# Launch an electron app and send data to it from a Web Browser (Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, electron, uri

I have a web application developed with php and mysql and I would like to launch a desktop application developed by electron js via a link from my web app and in the same time sending an array of images urls to my electron app that will download and store them on the user's machine somewhere for other processing.

**the process is like that i guess :**

- the user clicks to a link in the web app
- The electron app is launched.
- the urls of images are received and downloaded by the app.
- And other processing...

.

I am new to **electron js**, according to my research. I guess I have to use the URL Protocol handling
But I do not know how to do, and how to achieve that, if anyone can help i would be very grateful!

If you want any other explanation, I'm here and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'll also be looking into the URL protocol thing for my application too in the future, but for now, it's not a big concern for me. For anyone else having the same problem, please have a look at the Electron documents [[https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol]](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/protocol).

I'll edit my reply with my solution if I get mine to work.